# Datatable foreach detail/child row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to display foreach child row datatable

lets say I have ajax data like this

```
"data": [
{
  "date"      : "1/17/2016",
  "supplier"  : "supplier1",
  "total"     : "$10",
  "payment"   : "Cash",
  "product" : Array[2] 
     0: "product1"
     1: "product2"
  "price" : Array[2]
     0: "$5"
     1: "$5"
},
{
  "date"      : "2/1/2016",
  "supplier"  : "supplier2",
  "total"     : "$3",
  "payment"   : "Cash",
  "product" : Array[1] 
     0: "product1"
  "price" : Array[1]
     0: "$3"
},
{
  "date"      : "1/17/2016",
  "supplier"  : "supplier3",
  "total"     : "$15",
  "payment"   : "Cash",
  "product" : Array[3] 
     0: "product1"
     1: "product2"
     2: "product3"
  "price" : Array[2]
     0: "$3"
     1: "$5"
     2: "$7"
},
```

I wanna create datatable child row for `product & price` array following link [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

I only edit script in `function format` to meet my need like this

```
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table class="table table-border table-hover">'+
      '<tr>'+
         '<td>Product</td>'+
         '<td>Price</td>'+
      '</tr>' +

      '<?php 
          $loop = 5; 
          echo $loop;             <-- here

          for ($i=0; $i<$loop; $i++) {                      
             echo "<tr><td>'+d.product['$i']+'</td> <td>'+d.price['$i']+'</tr>"; 
       } ?>' +

    '</table>';
}
```

it's run quite well...I can display data like i want..but i must define `$loop` manual...

I tried using `$loop = "'+d.product.length+'"` 
when i `echo` that var in php 
it's display real value 
(say i have `3` array in `product` it's display `3` too)
but somehow when it's enter `for` section it's like `$loop` become 0 
because not display anyrow (if i set condition to `$i<=$loop` it's dispaly one row detail in every row parents)

i found something weird too 
`$loop = "'+d.product_.length+'" . "'+d.product_.length+'"`;
`echo $loop` ==> `33` *(say if product array count is `3`)*

but if I change it to `sum` it's result `0`
`$loop = "'+d.product_.length+'" + "'+d.product_.length+'"`;
`echo $loop` ==> `0` *(say if product array count is `3` too)*

how to solve it, so i can know how many looping should my script do

Comment: @GuruprasadRao don't have idea how to add my ajax datasource in demo...but i guess it's like this https://jsfiddle.net/nnb97rh9/47/   would you mind help edit so my ajax data (in top post) can be included?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao my problem basicly is to set var `$loop` automaticly...but i guess php messing around when it comes to set `$loop` with `javascript var`.....i guess i take wrong aproach

Comment: @GuruprasadRao can you give example, not quite understand..i'm still learning ajax & jquery :D..i will add my real data to my post too...wait a minute

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i just need to copy returned json in `console.log` right..if not...can you give me link tutorial how can i get correct json data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need `php` here to append your extra table with a loop, rather you can use `jquery`'s `$.each`.. You just need to construct your table body structure prior to `append` as below:

```
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    console.log(d.product);
    var trs=''; //just a variable to construct
    $.each($(d.product),function(key,value){
        trs+='<tr><td>'+value+'</td><td>'+d.price[key]+'</td></tr>';
        //loop through each product and append it to trs and am hoping that number of price 
        //values in array will be equal to number of products
    })
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table class="table table-border table-hover">'+
           '<thead>'+
              '<th>Product</th>'+
                '<th>Price</th>'+  
           '</thead><tbody>' 
               + trs +
        '</tbody></table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kshkrao3/JsonFileSample/master/Employees.json',
        "columns": [
            {
                "class":          'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "date"},
            { "data": "supplier"},
            { "data": "total"},
            { "data": "payment"}
        ]
    });

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
   $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
          // This row is already open - close it
          row.child.hide();
          tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
          // Open this row
          row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
          tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
});
```

> Note : There was an error in your `click event`.. You were trying `dTable.row` in the event where as it has to be `table.row` since you are holding reference in `table` variable.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/nnb97rh9/50/)**